# What time of the week would people like to hold town hall meetings (if any such thing at all)?

Tags: discussion, participation, chat, town-hall

Many sites schedule a chat in one of the chat rooms, at a certain time each week.

Quantum Computing has the "Quantum Revolution" every Tuesday at the same hour, and Meta.SE has the "Happy Hour" at 4pm EST every Friday.

I would be very keen to talk to people here, and even get feedback from a lot of the new users here that I don't yet know personally.

**Who here wants to do this sort of thing, and what time of the week do you think would be best?**

Keep in mind that out of our 10 most active users, we have:

- 1 person in Brazil
- 1 person in India
- 1 person in Taiwan
- 1 person in Finland
- 2 people in CDT (2 in USA)
- 4 people in EST (2 in Canada, 2 in USA)

In our list of 10 next most active users (meaning still in the top 20 most active users) we have people in Mexico, Spain, France, Chile, and Russia.

It might be very difficult to come up with a time that is convenient for *everyone*, but it is certainly not impossible (for example night time in the Americas and morning time in Taiwan). Also, if some of the most active users from any of the above time zones have no interest in weekly chats, then perhaps they can let us know, and while we would still try to choose a time that works for people in that time zone (since *others* in the time zone might indeed be interested) it might make it a bit easier for us to choose a time knowing that the most active person/people from that time zone are not interested.